# Nested NSDictionary in TXTRecordData Returns NULL

Tags: objective-c, nsnetservice

I'm using `NSNetService` and want to store some data in `TXTRecordData`. If I just store an `NSString`, it works OK - but if I store a nested dictionary then `dataFromTXTRecord...` returns nil.  For example:

```
NSData* d = [NSNetService dataFromTXTRecordDictionary:@{@"A": @"B"}];
// d != nil

NSData* d = [NSNetService dataFromTXTRecordDictionary:@{@"A": @{@"X":@"Y"}}];
// d == nil
```

Obviously I seem to be abusing TXTRecordData but I'd like to understand what's going on. I even tried to serialize my nested dictionary to a string, but it still returns nil. TXTRecordData seems very particular.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Bonjour/DNS text record can only store a flat list of key/value pairs, not an arbitrary nested dictionary.

From [DNS-SD (Rendezvous) TXT record format](http://www.zeroconf.org/Rendezvous/txtrecords.html):

> DNS-SD uses DNS TXT records to store arbitrary name/value pairs
>   conveying additional information about the named service. Each
>   name/value pair is encoded as it's own constituent string within the
>   DNS TXT record, in the form "name=value". Everything up to the first
>   '=' character is the name. Everything after the first '=' character to
>   the end of the string (including subsequent '=' characters, if any) is
>   the value.

Comment: Both the key & value must be a string. Total length of each pair must be 255 or less bytes. Total length of TXTRecord can be 65535 but under 400 is recommended. Pairs are serialized into bytes like `[length][key][=][value]` - where length is 1 byte, key may not contain `=` and value may contain any byte value. No separator between pairs.